# How can I refresh SaaS demo server daily to original state?

Tags: ubuntu

We provide a SaaS service and there is a demo server. I would like refresh this server daily to avoid the clutter.

Since the server is running on AWS, I could always stop, attach a fresh copy of the EBS volume and relaunch through a script but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this...

Comment: There probably is.  Maybe something like truncating a database table.  The trouble is, without knowing your software inside out, there's no way we can answer this for you.  Have you tried asking your dev team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only generic solution is the one you've already discovered. Anything more elegant will have to be application-aware, and for that you'll have to speak to the developers.

Comment: Thank you, I think this one is easy enough, I won't bother the developers for now.